# Are "спорить" and English "spar" cognates?

Tags: этимология

Do `спорить` and `spar` have any common etymological root?

EDIT: I'm referring specifically to the usage of `spar` for training for a fight or engaging in an argument.

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/etymology-of-the-word-sport?s=1|45.5576

Answer (score 6):

Maybe there's maybe there isn't

**spar (v)**

> late 14c., "go quickly, rush, dart, spring;" c. 1400, "to strike or
>   thrust," perhaps from Middle French esparer "to kick" (Modern French
>   éparer), from Italian sparare "to fling," **from Latin ex- (see ex-) +
>   parare "make ready, prepare," hence "ward off, parry" (from PIE root
>   [*pere-(1)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*pere-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to produce, procure")**. Etymologists consider a connection with spur unlikely.
>   Used in 17c. in reference to preliminary actions
>   in a cock fight; figurative sense of "to dispute, bandy with words" is
>   from 1690s.
>   Extension to humans, in a literal sense, with meaning "to
>   engage in or practice boxing" is attested from 1755. Related: Sparred;
>   sparring.

[Source](https://www.etymonline.com/word/spar)

**спорить**

> далее от праслав. *sъporъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли:
>   др.-русск. съпоръ, также соупоръ (из *сѫ-поръ), русск. спор; связано с
>   ***pьr- (пере́ть)**. Ср. **др.-инд. pŕ̥t-, pŕ̥tanā** «борьба», авест. pǝrǝt-, рǝšаnā «схватка, борьба»

[Source](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)

In the Russian word **C-** is a prefix, the root is **ПР**. In the English,  **S** could be a remnant of the Latin prefix **EX-**. Hard to tell whether this is coincidence or a result of common ancestry, although for greater semantic similarity the Russian prefix would perhaps have to be **ИЗ-** instead of **С-**.

I believe Russian cognates or relatives of **спорить** are **перечить, поперёк, наперекор, препираться**, and maybe even **против**, which either don't have prefix or have different prefixes. But this is only an opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I actually meant a different meaning of "spar," as in practicing for a fight or verbal sparing, which has a more similar meaning to the Russian word. According to the New Oxford American Dictionary, its etymology is a bit different:
"Old English sperran, spyrran ‘strike out’, of unknown origin; compare with Old Norse sperrask ‘kick out’."
But none of these have the ПР root so they are probably unrelated.

Comment: @dpc my bad, it was my inattentiveness, i've modified the answer

Comment: This is a really informative, thorough answer. I would upvote twice if I could.